# Oracle Apex set page item on Modal Dialog

Tags: jquery, plsql, server, oracle-apex

I try to set a value of an Item of another Page(Modal Dialog) which I open with a button. Usually I would just use the set page items option but it is not working. I try to transfer an ID to my Modal Dialog which I set by using JQuery ($s). After that I have a PL SQL Block that submits the ID Item but it still does not open the right values on my Modal Dialog.

Here is what happens:

Eventough the value of my ID gets refreshed in my Session it will only open the Modal Dialog with the right values AFTER I refresh the whole page. If I change my ID after the refresh it will still only open values that are connected to the old ID. (Until I refresh again)

What should happen:

Every single time I change my ID by using JQuery it should also open Modal Dialog with the right values connected to the ID. This should happen without the need of a page submit or refresh.

Q: Is it possible to achieve this without the need of page submitting or refreshing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution we came up with:
Both ID-Items of the Pages get these Settings:
[image]

After that u normally want to submit your first ID-Item via PLSQL to the server.(Page Items to submit)
If you then open your Modal Dialog with a Button you shouldnt set the ID values there but rather as a Process before the "Initialize Form Process" or with a "Before Header Process"  if you dont use a Form.